# SignalR propose "CallBackId"

Tags: android, signalr

As [document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.signalr.client.hubs.hubinvocation.callbackid(v=vs.118).aspx) said ...

**HubInvocation.CallbackId Property**

Gets or sets the callback identifier of the hub invocation property.

```
[JsonPropertyAttribute("I")]
public string CallbackId { get; set; }
```

---

what is propose of this value ?

it increases every time I got return from receive() function

```
    connection.received(new MessageReceivedHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onMessageReceived(JsonElement json) {
            Log.e("Received", json.toString());
            //ex log result: E/Received﹕ {"I":"70"}
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

SignalR uses `CallbackId` internally to track invocations. Each time you call `Invoke` it will be assigned an Id that will be sent to the server. When the server returns your call it include the `CallbackId` so that the client can correlate the result with the corresponding invocation.